# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

Hi I tried this code to get data from my API with AngularJS. I'm also using webix to show my datatables and to populate them.

My code for fetching data from API is:

```
var thedata = webix.ajax("app_dev.php/api/secure/cases"+caseid)
  .then(function(data){
      return data.json().correspondences;
  });
```

And my datatable looks something like this

```
{ view:"datatable",
 autoConfig:true,
 data:thedata }
```

But when I execute it in browser to show data in datatable I have this kind of error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

Any idea for this kind of error?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is `caseid` and where is it defined?

Comment: basically, you get this error when some function calls it recursively without an end. its not clear from your code what it does. But certainly some of your functions keeps calling itself recursively

Comment: webix.attachEvent("onBeforeAjax", function(mode, url, data, request, headers){
        headers["Authorization"]= CookieService.get('token');
        headers["Content-type"]= "application/json";
    });
    var caseid = $stateParams.casecorrespondenceid;
    if(caseid) {
        $http.get("secure/cases/"+caseid).success( function(response) {
            $scope.data = response;

       });
}                                                                                                                 This is how i define caseid and complete controller code.